# Hiding/Removing headers, footers & side navigation from an asp.net document that is in an iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I am a newbie at this web stuff and am stuck trying to figure out how to strip the headers, footers and side navigation from a document that is being used as the source for the iframe. I have a document page that is displayed in an iframe, but it is displaying everything like the navigation sidebars and the header and footer. Unfortunately, this document page by itself needs the navigation stuff on the top and side, but when displayed in the iframe, it will confuse the user as the unwanted stuff is duplicated with the parent page. So.... How do I remove the side navigation, header and footer?

I am using asp.net. The document is being set in the code behind using attributes (i.e. `iframe.Attributes.Add("src", "index.aspx"))`. So I need to strip out the unwanted stuff before loading it into the iframe and cannot seem to find any methods of achieving this, nor can I find any references on the internet. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a iframe (print in the article given) stylesheet  as per http://www.killersites.com/articles/newsletterArchive/Newsletter_Nov3_2003.htm.

Then when you are calling from ASP.net, you can open the page with the new CSS.

Hope this helps.